# Purchase made via Paypal, any way to change the grand total?

Tags: checkout, coupon, discount

A discount coupon was set to "Fixed amount discount" which will apply the coupon to each item in the cart. But the correct configuration should be "Fixed amount discount for whole cart".

Problem is the customer already paid using Paypal. Is there a way to rectify this?

The status of order in the admin panel is "Processing"

The invoice status is "Paid"

The transaction Is Closed is set to "No"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could contact the customer and notify him about the mistake.
Following this you should either make a credit note or have him pay the difference outside of Magento (whatever he prefers). This way your problem is solved and your customer is helped either way.